# ROW_NUMBER() OVER Function did not run through all records

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table like this

```
ID  Date    Sale    Sale_desc
1   1/1/2017    10  book
1   1/1/2017    10  book
1   1/1/2017    10  book
2   1/2/2017    12  notebook
2   1/2/2017    12  notebook
3   1/3/2017    1   pen
3   1/3/2017    1   pen
```

I ran the following query to get the row number:

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) 
from the_table;
```

But the result was not what I expected.

```
ID  Date        Sale    Sale_desc   row_num
1   1/1/2017    10      book        1
1   1/1/2017    10      book        1
1   1/1/2017    10      book        1
2   1/2/2017    12      notebook    1
2   1/2/2017    12      notebook    2
3   1/3/2017    1       pen         1
3   1/3/2017    1       pen         2
```

The row_num for the first 3 rows should be 1, 2, 3 but it looks like the row_num() did not run through all the rows. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Try to put everything necessary for understanding your question in the text of the question.

Comment: That looks strange, it's correct for the other IDs. You can rewrite it to `COUNT(*) over (partition by id order by date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`, check if this returns the correct result.

Comment: Which database is it, anyway? It works correctly on 11g XE (i.e. just as you wanted it to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the same code, I get the results you expect.  I made some assumptions about the column types that may be different than the ones you are using.  I am testing with the default collation, and that can affect string comparisons.

If you run the same test case and get the correct results, then the issue is somewhere else in the code.  We would need to see more of the original query and schema to find the problem.

```
declare @Test table
(
    ID int,
    [Date] Date,
    Sale int,
    Sale_desc varchar(50)
)

insert into @Test
(ID, [Date], Sale, Sale_desc)
select 1, '1/1/2017', 10, 'book'     union all
select 1, '1/1/2017', 10, 'book'     union all
select 1, '1/1/2017', 10, 'book'     union all
select 2, '1/2/2017', 12, 'notebook' union all
select 2, '1/2/2017', 12, 'notebook' union all
select 3, '1/3/2017', 1 , 'pen'      union all
select 3, '1/3/2017', 1 , 'pen'

select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [date]) as row_num
from @test
```

Results:

```
ID  Date        Sale  Sale_desc   row_num
1   2017-01-01  10    book        1
1   2017-01-01  10    book        2
1   2017-01-01  10    book        3
2   2017-01-02  12    notebook    1
2   2017-01-02  12    notebook    2
3   2017-01-03  1     pen         1
3   2017-01-03  1     pen         2
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your `id` column is string (`VARCHAR/CHAR`). You could try:

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by CAST(id AS INTEGER) order by date) 
from the_table;
```

**[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/JCUP63666)**

Comment: if it's about the data type, it would not work for the rest of the data. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: @DanTr This is wild guess based on limited info. Your code should work "as-is". I described scenario when what you see is not what you get.